# TensorFlow : How do i find my output node in my Tensorflow trained model?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am quite new in using Tensorflow, this is a sample of code that i found while googling. I tried to freeze the graph but it said that i need to input the correct output node. Since i am new to this, i am having a hard time to understand it. How do i find my output node in this code or do i need to freeze the whole graph?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys


class Seq2Seq(object):

    def __init__(self, xseq_len, yseq_len, 
            xvocab_size, yvocab_size,
            emb_dim, num_layers, ckpt_path,
            lr=0.0001, 
            epochs=200, model_name='seq2seq_model'): 
        # attach these arguments to self
        self.xseq_len = xseq_len
        self.yseq_len = yseq_len
        self.ckpt_path = ckpt_path
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.model_name = model_name


        # build thy graph
        #  attach any part of the graph that needs to be exposed, to the self
        def __graph__():

            # placeholders
            tf.reset_default_graph()
            #  encoder inputs : list of indices of length xseq_len
            self.enc_ip = [ tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], 
                            dtype=tf.int64, 
                            name='ei_{}'.format(t)) for t in range(xseq_len) ]

            #  labels that represent the real outputs

            self.labels = [ tf.placeholder(shape=[None,], 
                            dtype=tf.int64, 
                            name='ei_{}'.format(t)) for t in range(yseq_len) ]

            #  decoder inputs : 'GO' + [ y1, y2, ... y_t-1 ]
            self.dec_ip = [ tf.zeros_like(self.enc_ip[0], dtype=tf.int64, name='GO') ] + self.labels[:-1]


            # Basic LSTM cell wrapped in Dropout Wrapper
            self.keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            # define the basic cell
            basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(
                    tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(emb_dim, state_is_tuple=True),
                    output_keep_prob=self.keep_prob)
            # stack cells together : n layered model
            stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.core_rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([basic_cell]*num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)


            # for parameter sharing between training model
            #  and testing model
            with tf.variable_scope('decoder') as scope:
                # build the seq2seq model 
                #  inputs : encoder, decoder inputs, LSTM cell type, vocabulary sizes, embedding dimensions
                self.decode_outputs, self.decode_states = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq(self.enc_ip,self.dec_ip, stacked_lstm,
                                                    xvocab_size, yvocab_size, emb_dim)
                # share parameters
                scope.reuse_variables()
                # testing model, where output of previous timestep is fed as input 
                #  to the next timestep
                self.decode_outputs_test, self.decode_states_test = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.embedding_rnn_seq2seq(
                    self.enc_ip, self.dec_ip, stacked_lstm, xvocab_size, yvocab_size,emb_dim,
                    feed_previous=True)

            # now, for training,
            #  build loss function

            # weighted loss
            #  TODO : add parameter hint
            loss_weights = [ tf.ones_like(label, dtype=tf.float32) for label in self.labels ]
            self.loss = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss(self.decode_outputs, self.labels, loss_weights, yvocab_size)
            # train op to minimize the loss
            self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(self.loss)

        sys.stdout.write('<log> Building Graph ')
        # build comput graph
        __graph__()
        sys.stdout.write('</log>')



    '''
        Training and Evaluation

    '''

    # get the feed dictionary
    def get_feed(self, X, Y, keep_prob):
        feed_dict = {self.enc_ip[t]: X[t] for t in range(self.xseq_len)}
        feed_dict.update({self.labels[t]: Y[t] for t in range(self.yseq_len)})
        feed_dict[self.keep_prob] = keep_prob # dropout prob
        return feed_dict

    # run one batch for training
    def train_batch(self, sess, train_batch_gen):
        # get batches
        batchX, batchY = train_batch_gen.__next__()
        # build feed
        feed_dict = self.get_feed(batchX, batchY, keep_prob=0.5)
        _, loss_v = sess.run([self.train_op, self.loss], feed_dict)
        return loss_v

    def eval_step(self, sess, eval_batch_gen):
        # get batches
        batchX, batchY = eval_batch_gen.__next__()
        # build feed
        feed_dict = self.get_feed(batchX, batchY, keep_prob=1.)
        loss_v, dec_op_v = sess.run([self.loss, self.decode_outputs_test], feed_dict)
        # dec_op_v is a list; also need to transpose 0,1 indices 
        #  (interchange batch_size and timesteps dimensions
        dec_op_v = np.array(dec_op_v).transpose([1,0,2])
        return loss_v, dec_op_v, batchX, batchY

    # evaluate 'num_batches' batches
    def eval_batches(self, sess, eval_batch_gen, num_batches):
        losses = []
        for i in range(num_batches):
            loss_v, dec_op_v, batchX, batchY = self.eval_step(sess, eval_batch_gen)
            losses.append(loss_v)
        return np.mean(losses)

    # finally the train function that
    #  runs the train_op in a session
    #   evaluates on valid set periodically
    #    prints statistics
    def train(self, train_set, valid_set, sess=None ):

        # we need to save the model periodically
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        # if no session is given
        if not sess:
            # create a session
            sess = tf.Session()
            # init all variables
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        sys.stdout.write('\n<log> Training started </log>\n')
        # run M epochs
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            try:
                self.train_batch(sess, train_set)
                if i and i% (self.epochs//5) == 0: # TODO : make this tunable by the user
                    # save model to disk
                    saver.save(sess, self.ckpt_path + self.model_name + '.ckpt', global_step=i)
                    # evaluate to get validation loss
                    val_loss = self.eval_batches(sess, valid_set, 16) # TODO : and this
                    # print stats
                    print('\nModel saved to disk at iteration #{}'.format(i))
                    print('val   loss : {0:.6f}'.format(val_loss))
                    sys.stdout.flush()
            except KeyboardInterrupt: # this will most definitely happen, so handle it
                print('Interrupted by user at iteration {}'.format(i))
                self.session = sess
                return sess

    def restore_last_session(self):
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        # create a session
        sess = tf.Session()
        # get checkpoint state
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(self.ckpt_path)
        # restore session
        if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        # return to user
        return sess

    # prediction
    def predict(self, sess, X):
        feed_dict = {self.enc_ip[t]: X[t] for t in range(self.xseq_len)}
        feed_dict[self.keep_prob] = 1.
        dec_op_v = sess.run(self.decode_outputs_test, feed_dict)
        # dec_op_v is a list; also need to transpose 0,1 indices 
        #  (interchange batch_size and timesteps dimensions
        dec_op_v = np.array(dec_op_v).transpose([1,0,2])
        # return the index of item with highest probability
        return np.argmax(dec_op_v, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You first need to read/load your already frozen graph.

```
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # Then, we import the graph_def into a new Graph and return it 
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        # The name var will prefix every op/nodes in your graph
        # Since we load everything in a new graph, this is not needed
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
    return graph
```

Once you have loaded your already frozen `graph`, you can print all the operators in your `graph` like this:

```
for op in graph.get_operations(): 
    print(op.name, op.outputs)
```

Ref: The above code snippet is based on [this](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc) tutorial.

You can find your output node in the printed output. It should be similar to what was initially set in the tutorial you are following. Once you have found your output node name, you can actually get the tensor like this:

```
# This line is from my graph where the operator's name is "y_" and the value is ":0 "    
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/y_:0')
```

Note 1: Variable names in your code might be different from those mentioned here.

Note 2: Working with TensorFlow in the beginning can be overwhelming with all the different methods and properties to take care of. I suggest starting small to get the understanding of TensorFlow and then go ahead with a long example like the one you are following. You might want to go through the tutorial referenced in this answer, try to understand that, and then draw parallels with the sample code you are following.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have managed to freeze the graph. But when i tried to load it back. It give an error like this "Cannot convert a tensor of type float32 to an input of type float32_ref." Any idea why?

Comment: That might be your example-related. You will be better off Googling this one.

Comment: Side note: op.value has been deprecated. Use op.outputs. Also the command should be: print (op.name, op.outputs)                                                             --> don't include the extra parenthesis around the attributes